# My Regex returns nothing. Why?

Tags: php, regex

I get the content from an URL: http://money18.on.cc/js/real/hk/quote/16981_r.js

The content of this file is something like this:

```
M18.r_16981 = {
    "ltt": '2018/06/21 11:43',
    "np": '0.050',
    "iep": '0.000',
    "iev": '0',
    "ltp": '0.050',
    "vol": '940000',
    "tvr": '49860',



    "dyh": '0.060',
    "dyl": '0.049'
};
```

I want to extract the number after "vol", i.e. 940000.

And this is my php:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://money18.on.cc/js/real/hk/quote/16981_r.js");

echo $content."<br>";

preg_match("/(?<=vol\": ').*(?=', \"tvr)/", $content, $output_array);

print_r(array_values($output_array));
?>
```

The result returns nothing. Is the Regex wrong or any other problem?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of strange content format is this? is this meant to be JSON? do you control the content?

Comment: Are there more complex scenarios that you're trying to handle? Seems that `\"vol\":\s*'(\d+)'` should work just fine for what you've described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your positive lookahead `(?=` you could replace the whitespace with [`\s*`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to match zero or more (or `\s+` to match one or more) whitespace characters.

`(?<=vol": ').*(?=',\s*"tvr)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvLOMo/1)

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/u09XU)

Comment: if anyone just incase wants to know if it really works on the `file_get_contents` flavor https://www.tehplayground.com/PTNMZMcztkDhwm2R +1

Comment: @Ghost Awesome tip! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a long shot but...

If that content is actually meant to represent JSON and you have control over it:
get it into proper format as it is much easier and secure to get the data you want out of it then.

```
$jsonString = <<<JSON
{
    "ltt": "2018/06/21 11:43",
    "np": "0.050",
    "iep": "0.000",
    "iev": "0",
    "ltp": "0.050",
    "vol": "940000",
    "tvr": "49860",
    "dyh": "0.060",
    "dyl": "0.049"
}
JSON;

$jsonAsArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
var_dump($jsonAsArray['vol']);
```